# Size of 2D array in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I need to get the size of the second level in a 2D array. I'm trying this:

```
my @txt;
$txt[0][0]="text1";
$txt[0][1]="text2";
$txt[0][2]="text3";

$txt[1][0]="text4";
$txt[1][1]="text5";
$txt[1][2]="text6";

print scalar(@txt[1]);
```

But it doesn't work, and I see "ARRAY(0x804daf0)". How to get the size of the second dimension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`print scalar @{ $txt[1] };` should do the trick...

Comment: this gives the length of the rows, do you know how to get the length of the columns ?